# Java Web Start application autoload

Tags: java, autoload, java-web-start

Is there a way to make JWS application be runnable on system startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as easy as launching the [`javaws`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/javaws.html) command with the target JNLP URL on system startup.  My Windows scripting is a bit rusty but you could do something like this:

```vb
rem In "autoexec.bat", or another system startup script.
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaws http://my.domain.com/myjavawsapp.jnlp
```

I'm not sure if "`autoexec.bat`" is a good place for startup items any more but there should be plenty of alternatives like the Start Menup "Startup" folder, Services, and registry entries, etc.  Ultimately you just need to call the "javaws" program with your URL.

Comment: +1. You may also save jnlp file locally and load that using javaws.

Comment: The JNLP will always be saved locally anyway.

Comment: @Stefan: true, unless the app hasn't been run on that machine yet, in which case it couldn't have been cached.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the JNLP file in the startup process. Since the JNLP needs to be locally available anyway there is always a file on the machine. For windows you can check under Control panel -> Java -> Temporary Internet Files -> View and right click the app and choose show JNLP file.

Btw if you install the app through the web a copy is placed on your local machine.